# recursion function to get the title of a deeply nested HTML elemnt returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, dom

I have a function that goes down into an HTML element tree until it finds a specific A tag, it should return its title.

```js
    const myTitle = extractTitleFromNameWrapper(myElemnt);   // undefined
```

this not a problem with the logic, it is a problem **with the recursion**,  cause I don't know how many elements are there.

```js
function extractTitleFromNameWrapper(element) {
  var title;
  if (
    element.tagName === "A" 
  ) {
    console.log("title >>>>>>>>>> ", element.title);     // title here is defined
    title = element.title;
  }

  let children = [...element.children];
  if (children.length > 0) {
    children.forEach((el) => {
      title = extractTitleFromNameWrapper(el);
    });
  }
  return title;
}
```

I tried another way, basically returning from every branch:

```js
function extractTitleFromNameWrapper(element) {
  if (
    element.tagName === "A" 
  ) {
    console.log("title >>>>>>>>>> ", element.title); // title here is defined
    return element.title;
  }

  let children = [...element.children];
  if (children.length > 0) {
    return children.forEach((el) => extractTitleFromNameWrapper(el) );
  }

  return;
}
```

I also tried putting a variable out of the function and it did not work:

```js
var title1
extractTitleFromNameWrapper(muElem, title1);
console.log(title1); // undefined



function extractTitleFromNameWrapper(element, title) {
  if (
    element.tagName === "A" 
  ) {
    console.log("title >>>>>>>>>> ", element.title);     // title here is defined
    return title = element.title;
  }

  let children = [...element.children];
  if (children.length > 0) {
    children.forEach((el) => extractTitleFromNameWrapper(el) );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample DOM?

Comment: You've to return the title when you find it.

Comment: @Teemu I did that in the second and third stage, did not work

Comment: @srk Dom is complicated a bit, and I have to use this function many time

Comment: Have you heard of xPath?  It's a better way for finding matching DOM elements anywhere in your doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you make a recursive call for each child, but you never check the result of each call.

So in your first code snippet, I would expect to see something like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  title = extractTitleFromNameWrapper(children[i]);

  // If we find a title, stop looking!
  if (title) {
    break;
  }
}
```